# Assignability question in golang specification

Tags: go, language-specifications

While reading go specification "Assignability" section, I tried to execute a couple of examples to get a better understanding of the topic, and now I can't get what am I doing wrong in my code.

According to the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability),
One of the cases when a value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` is as follows:

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.

Defined type [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) states that

> Type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it.

But when I try to run following code, the build fails:

```
func main() {
    type Defined int32
    var d Defined
    var i int32
    d = i
}
```

The output is:

```
cannot use i (type int32) as type Defined in assignment
```

Meanwhile, the similar example with composite literal works fine:

```
func main() {
    type MyMap map[string]int
    var x MyMap 
    var y map[string]int
    x = y
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VCLrUJsAqJW)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also from the spec:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types

> To avoid portability issues all numeric types are defined types and thus distinct

Comment: So,  since both are defined types, they cannot be assigned to each other directly.  You can however say `d = Defined(i)`

Answer (score 4):

Since `type Defined int32` defines a new type, `d` and `i` don't have identical types; hence, the first clause *x's type is identical to T* from the [assignability spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) isn't applicable.  The second clause *x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type* is not applicable as the types of both `i` and `d` are defined types.  As the remaining clauses from the assignability spec do not apply in this situation, the assignment fails.  Changing `type Defined int32` to `type Defined = int32` (which aliases a type) fixes the error.

`x = y` due to the *T is an interface type and x implements T* clause from the assignability spec is applicable.